# Numpy appending to both elements of python list

Tags: python, numpy

```
data = load('data.npy')

def split_classes(data,col):
    newdata = []
    nclasses = len(unique(data[:,col]))
    classes = [[]] * nclasses
    for row in data:
        classes[int(row[col])].append(copy(row))
    print(len(classes[0]),len(classes[1]),len(data))
    return classes
split_classes(data,-1)
```

This just isn't doing what I want it to do.  Values are being added to each list within the python array. The output in this case being:
200 200 200

```
Example:
Input:
[[4, 2, 0]
 [3, 1, 0]
 [5, 9, 1]]
Output:
[[4, 2, 0],[3, 1, 0]],[5, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: Can you put some example input and output.  It's hard to understand what you want to do and what's going wrong without seeing your data before and after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the syntax `[[]] * nclasses` in Python, it does not mean you get `nclasses` number of distinct empty list objects. It means you get a list of length `nclasses` where each element is a handle to *the same* empty list. If one of them experiences an append operation, they all do.

Instead you could try `[[] for i in range(nclasses)]`. You can inspect the `id` of the different elements of `classes` to verify that indeed they have distinct object ids.

Consider a smaller example:

```
In [6]: x = [[] for i in range(3)]

In [7]: map(id, x)
Out[7]: [139882701328328, 139882701358288, 139882701358360]

In [8]: x[0].append(1)

In [9]: x
Out[9]: [[1], [], []]

In [10]: y = [[]] * 3

In [11]: y[0].append(1)

In [12]: y
Out[12]: [[1], [1], [1]]

In [13]: map(id, y)
Out[13]: [139882701358216, 139882701358216, 139882701358216]
```

Comment: In general, this means that it's OK to use the whole `[x] * k` trick to get `k` copies of `x` whenever `x` is something immutable, like a string, integer, float, or `tuple`. But when `x` is mutable, don't use the `[x] * k` trick, just explicitly initialize each location in the length-`k` array.